# Why am I not able to go to the next matching entry in vim by just pressing n?

Tags: vim, vi

[vimtutor](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vimtutor1.html) says this in `lesson 4.2 : The search command`

> 1. In Normal mode type the  /  character.  Notice that it and the cursor
>       appear at the bottom of the screen as with the  :  command.
>
>    2. Now type 'errroor' .  This is the word you want to search for.
>    3. To search for the same phrase again, simply type  n .
>         To search for the same phrase in the opposite direction, type  N .

This works perfectly while practicing with the vim tutor but I can't seem to get it to work with a file .basically when I type the `/` character and then key in the pattern to search , it is going to the first match as expected . But below the contents of the file I still see my search pattern with a blinking cursor . For example if I my pattern was the string `foo` , I see `/foo` and the cursor keeps blinking . Then pressing `n` just appends the the pressed character to the search string and the search pattern now becomes `/foon` which is not what I want .

Why am I seeing this issue and how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to conclude the search by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You're back in normal mode, where the `n` / `N` commands apply. As you may have noticed, Vim is a modal editor (best seen in that you need to press `i` to insert characters).

Vim *appears* to jump to the search pattern while you're typing it, but that's just a preview by the `'incsearch'` feature.

Answer (score 0):

> pressing n just appends the the pressed character to the search string and the search pattern now becomes /foon

vim is modal, it has **command mode** (where <kbd>n</kbd> means next match) and it has **insert mode** (where <kbd>n</kbd> means insert the character "n".)

It may be that you are using a special setup of vim, such as cream, that attempts to make vim act like a simple non-modal editor.

If you are using an unmodified vim with no unusual plugins or settings, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit insert-mode. The status line usually displays "INSERT" when in insert mode (but you can configure it not to - so check for this)

---

Update here's what you can expect to see in two different versions of Vim on two different platforms

Platform 1 - note status info is in reverse and includes flilename and an indicator that a change has been made (`[+]`)

1) After opening a file and typing `/hath`

[image]

2) After pressing <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

Platform 2 - note that all onscreen matches are highlighted.

1) After opening a file and typing `/hath`

[image]

2) After pressing <kbd>i</kbd>

[image]

Some aspects of Vim's appearance depend on version and configuration.

use `:ve` to display version of vim. It may help potential answerers for you to amend your question and include this information together with the name and version of operating system.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. The status line is not displaying "INSERT" but all i see is /foo and then a blinking cursor . And on pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> I see the line number,column number and a percentage like 19% at the extreme right.

Comment: Next if I press "n" , I see E:486 Pattern Not found :errroor . This string "errroor" incidentally the pattern that I practiced in vimtutor

Comment: when you press the "i" key to enter insert-mode, does it display "--INSERT --" on the line below the status line?